# standardization method using perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to do standardization (subtracting the mean from original value and dividing by stdev) using an automated script. 
I have a file with 10000 rows. I need to initially calculate mean and stdev for each column and then using those values I have to obatin the new standardized values.. I can do this pretty easily in excel.. But I am looking for an automated script.

input

```
DOTR1   10.29006    10.06744    10.47105    10.05041    10.18407    9.770205    10.90548    10.75112
RCC2    6.699481    7.240353    7.263434    6.654058    6.86063 7.151931    6.796337    6.78525
HHPA6   7.31182 7.547056    8.338827    7.278408    7.545548    7.409964    7.149899    7.300342
PAX8    8.336847    8.651292    8.493323    8.5056  8.445139    8.651406    8.664237    8.56571
ACA1A   4.233111    4.320666    4.232803    4.390224    4.269969    4.314899    4.264211    4.142419
UBA7    8.196608    8.164725    7.361889    8.055019    8.882745    7.6884  7.835754    8.354209
OOA 5.098222    5.212986    5.301191    5.211401    5.13133 5.153725    5.269111    5.195991
ACX1    4.875679    5.01305 4.921618    4.930978    4.899562    4.92918 4.970339    4.986362
```

The mean for column 1 is 6.880  and stdev is 2.066

I will now subtract the mean from my observation and divide by stdev to (10.29006-6.880)/2.066. I will do this on all subsequent observations row-wise in column 1. For column 2 again I will find its mean and corresponding stdev and follow the same procedure.

Thanks,

I tried the following code to get avg and stdev.. I am stuck with proceeding with the next step..

```
sub average{
    my($data) = @_;
    if (not @$data) {
            die("Empty array\n");
    }
    my $total = 0;
    foreach (@$data) {
            $total += $_;
    }
    my $average = $total / @$data;
    return $average;
}
 sub stdev{
    my($data) = @_;
    if(@$data == 1){
            return 0;
    }
    my $average = &average($data);
    my $sqtotal = 0;
    foreach(@$data) {
            $sqtotal += ($average-$_) ** 2;
    }
    my $std = ($sqtotal / (@$data-1)) ** 0.5;
    return $std;
}
```

Comment: What "next step" are you asking about?  Inputting from file?  Calculating the standardized values?

Comment: How are these subroutines being called?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array of arrays to represent the table. Go over the table column by column, get the mean and stdev, then replace each value in the column.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $IN, '<', 'input' or die $!;

my @table;

while (<$IN>) {
    $table[$. - 1] = [ split ];
}

for my $column (1 .. $#{ $table[0] }) {

    my $total = 0;
    $total   += $_ for map $table[$_][$column], 0 .. $#table;
    my $mean  = $total / @table;

    my $sqtot = 0;
    $sqtot   += ($mean - $_) ** 2 for map $table[$_][$column], 0 .. $#table;
    my $stdev = ($sqtot / $#table) ** 0.5;

    $table[$_][$column] = ($table[$_][$column] - $mean) / $stdev for 0 .. $#table;
}

$\ = "\n";
for my $line (@table) {
    print join "\t", @$line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post a solution I came up with, though its not as simple as choroba's. It uses [Statistics::Descriptive](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Statistics-Descriptive-3.0604/lib/Statistics/Descriptive.pm).

Update: Well, not a very good solution - creates 3 arrays when only one could be necessary for a solution. Disregard this solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Statistics::Descriptive;

my @data = map [split], <DATA>;

my @transpose = transpose(@data);
my @stats;

for my $row (@transpose[1.. $#transpose]) {
    my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new;
    $stat->add_data($row);
    push @stats, [$stat->mean, $stat->standard_deviation];
}

my @new;

for my $r (0 .. $#data) {
    my @tmp;
    for my $c (1 .. $#{$data[$r]}) {
        push @tmp, ($data[$r][$c] - $stats[$c-1][0]) / $stats[$c-1][1];
    }
    push @new, [$data[$r][0], map {sprintf "%.3f", $_} @tmp];
}

# output loop
for my $row (@new) {
    print join("\t", @$row), "\n";  
}

sub transpose {
    my @array = @_;

    my @trans;
    for my $i (0 .. $#array) {
        for my $j (0 .. $#{$array[$i]}) {
            $trans[$j][$i] = $array[$i][$j];    
        }   
    }
    return @trans;
}

__DATA__
DOTR1   10.29006    10.06744    10.47105    10.05041    10.18407    9.770205    10.90548    10.75112
RCC2    6.699481    7.240353    7.263434    6.654058    6.86063 7.151931    6.796337    6.78525
HHPA6   7.31182 7.547056    8.338827    7.278408    7.545548    7.409964    7.149899    7.300342
PAX8    8.336847    8.651292    8.493323    8.5056  8.445139    8.651406    8.664237    8.56571
ACA1A   4.233111    4.320666    4.232803    4.390224    4.269969    4.314899    4.264211    4.142419
UBA7    8.196608    8.164725    7.361889    8.055019    8.882745    7.6884  7.835754    8.354209
OOA 5.098222    5.212986    5.301191    5.211401    5.13133 5.153725    5.269111    5.195991
ACX1    4.875679    5.01305 4.921618    4.930978    4.899562    4.92918 4.970339    4.986362
```

Prints out:

```
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl t33.pl
DOTR1   1.650   1.516   1.624   1.610   1.490   1.502   1.797   1.698
RCC2    -0.087  0.106   0.102   -0.117  -0.079  0.140   -0.085  -0.102
HHPA6   0.209   0.259   0.612   0.200   0.245   0.274   0.077   0.132
PAX8    0.705   0.810   0.686   0.824   0.669   0.920   0.770   0.706
ACA1A   -1.281  -1.349  -1.335  -1.268  -1.301  -1.336  -1.244  -1.302
UBA7    0.637   0.567   0.149   0.595   0.875   0.419   0.391   0.610
OOA     -0.862  -0.904  -0.829  -0.851  -0.895  -0.900  -0.784  -0.824
ACX1    -0.970  -1.004  -1.009  -0.993  -1.004  -1.017  -0.921  -0.919
```